# Flexbox two rows same width with overflow

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to create a "simple" information bar that should be displayed inline.

The bar consist of two divs, where the first contains all the required info (and is always visible) and the second shows information messages when they apply.
I have created a pen to demonstrate [here](http://codepen.io/gkaran/pen/PqREYG).

My problem is that the content of the upper div is not always the same width and in some cases it overflows (which is a valid behavior based on my requirements since I always want it to be in one line). Thus when the screen gets shrinked enough the upper div overflows but the below keeps a width same as the screen width and does not follow the upper div's width.

What I want to achieve is make the below div have the same width as the upper even when the upper one overflows. Any ideas anyone?

Adding code here as well for reference:

***HTML:***

```
<h2> Shrink me to see than warning div is not the same width as the other one</h2>

<div id="TaskTimeBar">
  <div id='main-wrapper'>
    <div class="task-time-bar-content">
      <div id="time-cell">
        <div class='time-container'>
          <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>21:12
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="active-task-bar-main-content">
        <div><i class="fa fa-link"></i> <a href="/show?table=TASK&amp;key=28125">#28125</a></div>
        <div><i class="fa fa-info"></i> This can be a long text...</div>
        <div><i class="fa fa-user"></i> <a href="/show?table=Customer&amp;key=1">Yo mama</a></div>
      </div>
      <div id="active-task-bar-buttons">
        <div class="active-bar-button-wrapper">
          <button>Stop</button>
        </div>
        <div class="active-bar-button-wrapper">
          <button>Switch To #28192</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="active-task-bar-information">This is an information message</div>
</div>
```

***CSS:***

```
#TaskTimeBar {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-shrink: 0;
  -moz-flex-shrink: 0;
  -ms-flex-negative: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -moz-flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -moz-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
#main-wrapper {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-shrink: 0;
  -moz-flex-shrink: 0;
  -ms-flex-negative: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex-grow: 1;
  -moz-flex-grow: 1;
  -ms-flex-positive: 1;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
.task-time-bar-content {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-shrink: 0;
  -moz-flex-shrink: 0;
  -ms-flex-negative: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex-grow: 1;
  -moz-flex-grow: 1;
  -ms-flex-positive: 1;
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding: 5px;
}
#time-cell {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-shrink: 0;
  -moz-flex-shrink: 0;
  -ms-flex-negative: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex-grow: 1;
  -moz-flex-grow: 1;
  -ms-flex-positive: 1;
  flex-grow: 1;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 22px;
}
.time-container {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  -moz-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-flex-shrink: 0;
  -moz-flex-shrink: 0;
  -ms-flex-negative: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
.time-container i {
  padding-right: 5px;
}
#active-task-bar-main-content {
  padding: 0 10px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-shrink: 0;
  -moz-flex-shrink: 0;
  -ms-flex-negative: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  -webkit-box-pack: space-around;
  -ms-flex-pack: space-around;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-around;
  -moz-justify-content: space-around;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
#active-task-bar-main-content div {
  padding: 0 10px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}
#active-task-bar-buttons {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-shrink: 0;
  -moz-flex-shrink: 0;
  -ms-flex-negative: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  padding: 0 10px;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex-grow: 1;
  -moz-flex-grow: 1;
  -ms-flex-positive: 1;
  flex-grow: 1;
  -webkit-box-pack: end;
  -ms-flex-pack: end;
  -webkit-justify-content: flex-end;
  -moz-justify-content: flex-end;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
.active-bar-button-wrapper {
  line-height: 28px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-shrink: 0;
  -moz-flex-shrink: 0;
  -ms-flex-negative: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
.active-task-bar-information {
  background-color: #ffa500;
  color: #f3ebf8;
  border: thin solid #808080;
  border-top: none;
  text-align: center;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  -moz-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex-grow: 1;
  -moz-flex-grow: 1;
  -ms-flex-positive: 1;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

---

***Edit:***

Let me explain a little bit more based on the div's ids as asked in the comments.

I hava a `#TaskTimeBar` that contains two divs inside, `#main-wrapper` and `#active-task-bar-information`. Requirements are as follows:

- `#main-wrapper` should always be in one line
- `#active-task-bar-information` should always have the same width as `#main-wrapper` and be underneath it.

The problem is that when the screen becomes small the contents of `#main-wrapper` overflow and exceed the screen width but `#active-task-bar-information` does not follow. If you play around with the window width in the linked pen you will see the effect.

Comment: I'm a little confused, could you explain your objective and issue again but refer to the elements by the classes/ids you gave them?

Comment: I understand, they way I wrote it, it can be confusing. I updated the question (see edit in the end) to explain further in the way you asked. Thank you for your time.

Comment: I think you'll need `javascript` to get the upper `div`'s width and apply it to the bottom `div`

Comment: This is one option, yes. What I wanted was to eliminate that if possible though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to make sure I got this right:

- **main-wrapper** never actually wraps it's content, therefore it overflows.
- **active-task-bar-information** content actually wraps and never exceeds the viewport.
- **main-wrapper's** behavior is correct.
- **active-task-bar-information's** behavior is not correct. It should behave as it's sibling #main-wrapper.

Going by these criterions I think I got it. Try this:

```
html { box-sizing: border-box; font: 16px/1.5 Consolas; }
body { width: 100%; min-width: 60em; height: auto; }
*, *:before, *:after { box-sizing: inherit; margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0; }
#TaskTimeBar {

  display: -webkit-inline-box;
  display: -webkit-inline-flex;
  display: -moz-inline-box;
  display: -moz-inline-flex;
  display: -ms-inline-flexbox;
  display: inline-flex;
  -webkit-flex-shrink: 0;
  -moz-flex-shrink: 0;
  -ms-flex-negative: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -moz-flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: nowrap;
  -moz-flex-wrap: nowrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: nowrap;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  -webkit-box-pack: stretch;
  -ms-flex-pack: stretch;
  -webkit-justify-content: stretch;
  -moz-justify-content: stretch;
  justify-content: stretch;

}
#main-wrapper {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-shrink: 0;
  -moz-flex-shrink: 0;
  -ms-flex-negative: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex-grow: 1;
  -moz-flex-grow: 1;
  -ms-flex-positive: 1;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
.task-time-bar-content {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-shrink: 0;
  -moz-flex-shrink: 0;
  -ms-flex-negative: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex-grow: 1;
  -moz-flex-grow: 1;
  -ms-flex-positive: 1;
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding: 5px;
}
#time-cell {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-shrink: 0;
  -moz-flex-shrink: 0;
  -ms-flex-negative: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex-grow: 1;
  -moz-flex-grow: 1;
  -ms-flex-positive: 1;
  flex-grow: 1;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 22px;
}
.time-container {
  display: -webkit-inline-box;
  display: -webkit-inline-flex;
  display: -moz-inline-box;
  display: -moz-inline-flex;
  display: -ms-inline-flexbox;
  display: inline-flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  -moz-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-flex-shrink: 0;
  -moz-flex-shrink: 0;
  -ms-flex-negative: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
.time-container i {
  padding-right: 5px;
}
#active-task-bar-main-content {
  padding: 0 10px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-shrink: 0;
  -moz-flex-shrink: 0;
  -ms-flex-negative: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  -webkit-box-pack: space-around;
  -ms-flex-pack: space-around;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-around;
  -moz-justify-content: space-around;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
#active-task-bar-main-content div {
  padding: 0 10px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}
#active-task-bar-buttons {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-shrink: 0;
  -moz-flex-shrink: 0;
  -ms-flex-negative: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  padding: 0 10px;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex-grow: 1;
  -moz-flex-grow: 1;
  -ms-flex-positive: 1;
  flex-grow: 1;
  -webkit-box-pack: end;
  -ms-flex-pack: end;
  -webkit-justify-content: flex-end;
  -moz-justify-content: flex-end;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
.active-bar-button-wrapper {
  line-height: 28px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-shrink: 0;
  -moz-flex-shrink: 0;
  -ms-flex-negative: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
.active-task-bar-information {
  background-color: #ffa500;
  color: #f3ebf8;
  border: thin solid #808080;
  border-top: none;
  text-align: center;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  -moz-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex-grow: 1;
  -moz-flex-grow: 1;
  -ms-flex-positive: 1;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

To get more accurate results I reset everything to border-box sizing, zeroed all margins, paddings, and borders. That's optional.
I changed how the parent flexbox (**TaskTimeBar**) contents are kept since **main-wrapper** and **active-task-bar-information** are siblings. The changes are as follows:

```
#TaskTimeBar {...
.....
  -webkit-flex-wrap: nowrap;
  -moz-flex-wrap: nowrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: nowrap;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  -webkit-box-pack: stretch;
  -ms-flex-pack: stretch;
  -webkit-justify-content: stretch;
  -moz-justify-content: stretch;
  justify-content: stretch;
 }
```

**TaskTimeBar** (the parent) stretches it's children (**main-wrapper** and **active-task-bar-information**), past the viewport due to the `justify` property `stretch` and the `flex-wrap` property `nowrap`. As a side note, **active-task-bar-information** was always 2px shorter than **main-wrapper** until I did that reset and now they measure the same width in any sized viewport (as far as I'm able to determine).
Hopefully I understood your question properly and gave you appropriate advice.

**EDIT:** While I was fulfilling a request for a [demo][1], I added inline-flex to all three divs. Details are provided with the demo. Below are screenshots illustrating the 2 divs equal widths.

[image: **active-task-bar-information** 2383.328125px]
[image: **main-wrapper** 2383.328125px]

Comment: Hello. Do you have a demo/fiddle/pen?

Comment: @RamTobolski Done. I added a little more styling as well.

Comment: @zer00ne Thank you for the great response. From what I see though in your demo the problem still exists. If you go to the right side of the page, the link and buttons are outside the wrapper and the information bar underneath does not stretch enough "cover" those as well.

Comment: Oh, sorry I didn't see those requirements in your question, I thought you wanted the two divs at equal widths at all times. So you want everything within the viewport? I thought you wanted overflow, then inline-flex is definitely not what you need. Have you tried `max-width: 100vw` on the children divs?  Btw the `infobar` does stretch, it's just that the children of `main-wrapper` extend further than `main-wrapper` and `infobar`.

Answer (score -1):

In [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0nyL53y1/) I've taken @zer00ne's code, and tried to simplify the situation, by keeping only the outer div a flex-box, instead of managing a hierarchy of flex-boxes. I've kept the inner divs in line with `display: inline` and `white-space: nowrap`. Is seems to achieve the desired result.